# nodejs TLSSocket.onHangUp

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have 2 nodejs modules that communicate via HTTPS.

In very rare occasions, one of the requests to the server module returns:

Stack Trace

```
Error: socket hang up
    at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1049:19)
    at TLSSocket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:397:17)
```

with errno set to ECONNRESET

Is there any reason why something like that would happen?

I already checked for:

1. Server crashes before responding
2. Server response takes too long
3. certificate expired.

Also, the server logs do not show any kind of problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **ECONNRESET** (Connection reset by peer): A connection was forcibly closed by a peer. This normally results from a loss of the connection on the remote socket due to a timeout or reboot. Commonly encountered via the http and net modules.

#### "**Common System Errors**" : https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html

so try first to see what's happen

```
process.on("uncaughtException", function (err) {
  console.log('err uncaught Exception  : ', err);
})
```

Comment: The problem is that my server didn't crash and when i tried to mock crash or requests taking too long, the stack trace mapped to a different place.
This error occurs at _tls_wrap.js
When server closes or request timeouts, the error occurs in _http_client.js

Comment: can you provide us the code ? can't just find a solution like that

Comment: Code is not open-source.

Comment: I could not even reproduce this behavior on local env. It just happens on production(aws-elastic-bean-stalk)